# dynamic data in ChartJS

Tags: php, jquery, chart.js, jqvmap

I'm using ChartJS and JQVMaps in a website to create an interactive world map that displays info graphics when a user clicks on a region. The ChartJS plugin allows you to assign the chart's data values as an array like so:

```
var pieData = [
        {
            value: 20,
            color:"#878BB6"
        },
        {
            value : 40,
            color : "#4ACAB4"
        },
        {
            value : 10,
            color : "#FF8153"
        },
        {
            value : 30,
            color : "#FFEA88"
        }
    ];
```

For my project, I will need to generate these data values dynamically based on what region the user clicked. The final site will be through WordPress. Is it possible to feed the chart's build script

```
new Chart(pie).Pie(pieData);
```

a PHP or jQuery function that could call one of several different arrays in pieData? What might that coding look like? I'm somewhat new to PHP and jQuery so any help is greatly appreciated.

The [demo](http://jdillman.com/interactive_map-master/world_test.html) is up on [GitHub](http://github.com/jdillman1989/interactive_map) if you want to take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an AJAX request to get the data from the server.  Below is an example using PHP to build out data. Although you would need to make it conditional based on region.

```
onRegionClick: function(element, code, region) {
 $.ajax('/get_chart_data.php', {
  data: {region: region},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    new Chart(pie).Doughnut(response.pieData, pieOptions);
  }
});
```

get_chart_data.php

```
<?php

// Check which region was passed
//$_REQUEST['region']
// Based on region build chart data

$chartData = new stdClass();

$pieData = array();
$pie1= new stdClass();
$pie1->value = 20;
$pie1->color = '#878BB6';
$pieData[] = $pie1;

$pie2= new stdClass();
$pie2->value = 40;
$pie2->color = '#4ACAB4';
$pieData[] = $pie2;

$chartData->pieData = $pieData;
echo json_encode($chartData);
?>
```

One method of switching based on region

```
<?php

$region1Pie = array(20, '#878BB6', 40, '#4ACAB4', 10, '#FF8153', 30, '#FFEA88');
$region2Pie = array(15, '#878BB6', 20, '#4ACAB4', 25, '#FF8153', 30, '#FFEA88');
$region3Pie = array(9, '#878BB6', 60, '#4ACAB4', 25, '#FF8153', 12, '#FFEA88');

$chartData = new stdClass();
$pieData = array();

// Swtich based on region
switch($_REQUEST['region']) {
  case 1:
    $pieArray = $region1Pie;
    break;
  case 2:
    $pieArray = $region2Pie;
    break;
  case 3:
    $pieArray = $region3Pie;
    break;
}

for($i=0; $i<count($pieArray); $i+=2) {
  $pie= new stdClass();
  $pie->value = $pieArray[$i];
  $pie->color = $pieArray[$i+1];
  $pieData[] = $pie;
}

$chartData->pieData = $pieData;
echo json_encode($chartData);

?>
```

Comment: Now I just have to learn AJAX haha. Thanks so much for the tip, I'll make sure to give this a shot.

Comment: You must have actually looked at the demo to get the Doughnut(pieData, pieOptions); code, thanks! Would I really even need the last 3 lines of the onRegionClick code (where you set up the canvas and ctx variables and called a new Chart) if I just wanted to test this on the one Doughnut chart?

Comment: Based on your demo I don't think you need those.  The pie chart is initialized above with

var pie= document.getElementById("pie").getContext("2d");

So you would only need the following.  new Chart(pie).Doughnut(response.pieData, pieOptions); Your demo is working like that now so will be fine without those lines.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm getting a parse error on line 7 of get_chart_data.php (the $chartData = stdClass(); line). Is there something I need to do with parameters?

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting a parse error on that line. Also, I've set up a PHP switch around each $pie#= new stdClass(); to test for regionMap. Does that sound right?

Comment: There was a missing semicolon but other than that the code runs file.  A switch statement would work. I'm not sure how much data there is or where it's coming from. I posted an alternative method that might be easy to edit.  If you're just learning go with whatever works. Also I don't know what the value of region is, will need to update the switch.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much, that switch method looks so much nicer than what I had.

Comment: OK 1 more (hopefully) quick thing on this: I've been testing this code just by running a local PHP server through the Mac Terminal. It runs perfectly when I test it like this, but when I actually upload the files to my [site](http://jdillman.com/interactive_map/world_test.html), I get this error: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404. *Only China, Canada, and Brazil are working ATM.

Comment: Actually it is running on the public [server](http://jdillman.com/world_test.html) now, I just didn't realize it because the AJAX response takes an obscene amount of time. Is there any way to get the chart data faster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite easy. I am using bootstrap adminlte and want to show the donut chart.

The HTML Code is given below :

```
 <div class="chart-responsive">
     <canvas id="myChart" height="400"></canvas>
 </div>
```

Script File :

```
    /*
     * Declaration of Arrays
     */
    var dataCount = new Array();
    var labelSet = new Array();
    var colorArray = new Array();
    var colorHoverArray = new Array();
    var footerArray = new Array();
    /*
     * Footer color array (To set the color dynamically)
     */
    footerArray.push('green', 'orange', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red','purple');
     /*
     * Label color Array
     */
    colorArray.push('#3c8dbc', '#f56954', '#FFCE56', '#f56954', '#d2d6de', '#00a65a', '#00c0ef', '#605ca8', '#ff851b');

    /*
     * On Hover color Array
     */
    colorHoverArray.push('#605ca8', '#ff851b', '#00c0ef', '#00a65a', '#72dbdb', '#f56954', '#FFCE56', '#3c8dbc', '#f56954');
    var backgroundArray = new Array();
    var hoverArray = new Array();
    var listCount = 0;
    /*
     * Ajax call to get the response
     */
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: yourUrl',
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response.list, function (index, value) {
                /*
                 * dynamically loading the data in the array to pass it on to the datasets and labels Option
                 * of the Donut Chart
                 */
                dataCount[index] = value.usersCount;
                labelSet[index] = value.statusName;
                listCount = response.list.length;
            });

            /*
             * Background & hover color of the area on donut chart
             */
            for (var item = 0; item < listCount; item++)
            {
                backgroundArray[item] = colorArray[item];
                hoverArray[item] = colorHoverArray[item];
            }
            /*
             * Main donut chart section
             */
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
            var ctx = $("#myChart");
            var ctx = "myChart";
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var data = {
                labels: labelSet,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: dataCount,
                        backgroundColor: backgroundArray,
                        hoverBackgroundColor: hoverArray
                    }]
            };
            // And for a doughnut chart to render the data
            var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: data,
            });
        }
    });
```